# How to notify listfragment about database changes

Tags: android

i have list fragment which loads data from database, some of the services inserts log to database.

If the list is launched freshly, it loads all data & it works great. But the problem is, if the listview

is open & if some serviecs inserts data, list should get notified, how to do?

Comment: use a CursorLoader, it will automatically be reloaded if the db is altered

Comment: cursor loader works, if we insert data via that particular loader object. But in my case, in service i'm doing DB operation.

Comment: no, by default CursorLoader works with a custom ContentProvider, if the Service uses that ContentProvider all the CursorLoaders will be reloaded

Comment: I'm using simple sqliteloader, no content provider :(

Comment: so you have problems now...  use commonsware's advice then

Answer (score 0):

Have the service raise an event on an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), etc.), picked up by the list fragment, which reloads its contents.

Or, wrap the database in a `ContentProvider` and use `CursorLoader`.

Or, come up with some other way that the service can signal your UI layer (if it is around) so the UI layer knows to refresh its contents.

Comment: I'm using your sqlitecursorloader (i know its depricated :), i just want to signal or notify via some registered interface, i'm not getting exact idea. any sample example pls

Comment: @Naruto: Here are various event bus samples: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus